# subgroups complementing terms of the lower exponent-p central series (Huppert-Blackburn Th. VIII.1.7b))

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem VIII.1.7b) in Huppert-Blackburn "Finite Groups. II". It deals with what is elsewhere called the lower exponent-$p$ series of a group $G$, defined as:
$$\lambda_1(G)=G,\qquad \lambda_{n+1}(G)=[\lambda_{n}(G),G](\lambda_n(G))^p.$$
Theorem VIII.1.5b) says that

*If $H\le G$, and $H\lambda_2(G)=G$, then $H\lambda_n(G)=G$ for all $n\ge1$.*

The proof by induction is very short but I don't understand it:

---

Suppose that by induction hypothesis we have $G=H\lambda_n(G)$. Then:
$$\lambda_n(G)=[\lambda_{n-1}(G),G]\lambda_{n-1}(G)^p
\le [H\lambda_n(G),H\lambda_n(G)](H\lambda_n(G))^p
\le H\lambda_{n+1}(G),$$

from where we conclude that $G=H\lambda_n(G)\le H\lambda_{n+1}(G)$, and we are done.

---

I do not understand the inequality $[H\lambda_n(G),H\lambda_n(G)](H\lambda_n(G))^p
\le H\lambda_{n+1}(G)$ above. There is something very obvious to the authors used, but all my fiddling with commutators did not yield the required form on the right-hand side. Any hints?

Comment: That's not what my Theorem VIII.1.5b says.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Sorry, Th.1.7, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save typing, let $A=\lambda_n(G)$ and $B = \lambda_{n+1}(G)$.

Then (since $A \unlhd G$), we have
$$[HA,HA] = [H,H][H,A][A,A] \le H[G,A] \le HB,$$
and $$(HA)^p \le H^pA^p[H,A] \le HA^pB \le HB.$$

Comment: Dear Professor Holt, thank you for your answer! However, I do not understand the first equality: $[HA,HA]=[H,H][H,A][A,A]$. Could you possibly direct me to a reference? I know the identities $[xy,z]=[x,z]^y[y,z]$ and $[x,yz]=[x,z][x,y]^z$. From these, I got for $h,k\in H$, $a,b\in A$:
$$[ha,kb]=[h,b]^a[h,k]^{ba}[a,b][a,k]^b.$$
How do we conclude that the right-hand side has the form $[H,H][H,A][A,A]$, since $H$ is not necessarily normal in $G$?

Comment: $[h,k]^{ba} = [h,k][[h,k],ba]$ with $[[h,k],ba] \le [G,A] \le B$. So $[h,k]^{ba} \le [H,H]B$.